# Figure numbering incorrect when using subcaption package

Tags: floats, formatting, numbering, subfloats, subcaption

I can't seem to find the answer to my issues with figure numbering. I'm using the subcaption package and this should be Fig 1a and Fig 1b but the whole figure is labelled as Fig 2 in the pdf, I can work around this with referencing but it still shifts the further plots to the wrong numbering, for instance the second figure is now Fig 3, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[fleqn,usenatbib,useAMS]{mnras}

% according to the author-year natbib style
\usepackage{natbib}

%
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{txfonts}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}



\begin{document} 

\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=4.6in]{HR_nonrot.png}
        \subcaption{models without rotation}
            \label{fig:HRDnrot}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=4.6in]{HR_rot.png}
        \subcaption{models with rotation at v$_{\mathrm{ini}}$=0.4v$_{\mathrm{crit}}$ (red solid lines)}
        \label{fig:HRDrot}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{
    Evolutionary tracks of models in the mass range $9\msun \leq \mini \leq 120\msun$ until the end of He-burning. Key evolutionary stages are indicated.}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the subcaption is probably better to add the label as a part of the subcaption. If the does not work, please post a full minimal example instead of this sniplet that we cannot test on its own

Comment: Hi Laura and welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please provide a complete MWE including you preamble and setup pf the `subcaption` package?

Comment: Which package exactly do you use to number your subfigures?

Comment: Sorry for forgetting the preamble, just added it there!

Comment: I have tested it on another project and it numbered the figure correctly, and have discovered an error on my `\begin{document}` saying that the subcaption package doesn't work correctly on the original project where I'm having the issue, not sure what I'm doing differently though, any ideas?

Comment: I found the solution! I had to add `\captionsetup{compatibility=false}` underneath the preamble `\usepackage{subcaption}`, no idea why I didn't have to do this on the test project but it's solved the issue, thanks for your help!

Comment: There are many problems. One should use `subfig`, instead, with the `caption=false` option, but, unfortunately, `mnras` loads `hyperref`  (which is a bad thing). In any case, also with your (not recommended) workaround, `hyperref` cannot be aware that `subfig` or `subcaption` are loaded and low level errors appear connected with anchors.